# How to change the behavior of nodes (cars), rsu in Omnet++ Veins project

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I have setup my environment using omnet++, sumo and veins in ubuntu. I want to reduce packet loss in an emergency situation among vehicles and improve packet delivery time and cost. My project is about choosing the suitable processing position among cluster head (nodes), road side unit (rsu) and cloud. I want to achieve certain tasks that is need to implement my veins project. I have configured 50 nodes and 4 rsu and provide data rate about 6mbps and assign the packet size upto 2MB.

Therefore, how can I change the behavior of vehicles (nodes), road side unit (rsu) and cloud in order to implement the following parameters?

processing rate of clusters (nodes) = 3 Mbps.

processing rate of RSUs = 7 Mbps.

processing rate of cloud = 10 Mbps.

the range of clusters (nodes) = 60 m.

the range of RSU =  120 m.

the range of cloud = 500 m.

If you could help with building these parameters I will appreciate it.
Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't know which answer to give you that wouldn't involve writing all necessary code and configuration parameters for you. Can you rephrase your question so it is more general and less specific to the task you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just changed and rephrased now sir

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about transsmision rate, then you can set the bit rate in the ini file (check veins example) but if you meant processing delay then it is usually simulated by scheduling self messages (check tictoc example). In terms of transsmsion range, veins uses Free Space Propagation model and the related parameters are set in the ini file so you can change them to decide the required range. Finally, I recommand to read more about veins and how it deal with the parameters you asked about. There are alot of answered questions on StackOverFlow about your questions.